tcolorbox : image in title part - how to remove borders
I would like to decorate a tcolorbox with a picture.
The closest layout use title to control the position and reserve space.

I cannot remove the borders to have only image. What I am missing ?
\documentclass[
    a4paper, %metric pages
    twocolumn, %default two columns
    twoside, %odd and even page have different layout
    openany, %new chapter on verso page
    draft=false, %full mode
    fontsize=9pt, %default font size
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTColorBox{mybox}{O{}}{
    enhanced,
    colframe=black,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    frame hidden,
    interior hidden,
    coltitle=white,
    title style={fill=none, draw=none},
    notitle,
    width=\columnwidth,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-10mm},
    title={\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}},
    frame style tile={width=\tcb@width,height=\tcb@height}{example-image},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{mybox}
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{mybox}
    \lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}


You can set boxed title style to blankest.
\documentclass[
    a4paper, %metric pages
    twocolumn, %default two columns
    twoside, %odd and even page have different layout
    openany, %new chapter on verso page
    draft=false, %full mode
    fontsize=9pt, %default font size
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\DeclareTColorBox{mybox}{O{}}{
    enhanced,
    colframe=black,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    frame hidden,
    interior hidden,
    coltitle=white,
    title style={fill=none, draw=none},
    notitle,
    width=\columnwidth,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-10mm},
    boxed title style={blankest},
    title={\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}},
    frame style tile={width=\tcb@width,height=\tcb@height}{example-image},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{mybox}
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{mybox}
    \lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}



Thank you! It works.
